# What am I doing wrong the last part doesn't open a box or give an error?

Tags: java

I have tried so many things and one part will run and the other won't give me an error but the box won't open with the answer I am looking for. I am not sure if I posted my question exactly correct this is my first time, nor do I know where to post the program I have been working on. I am sorry if I bothered you I did search and read and am at my wits end. – Pamela Hayer 16 hours ago

Try posting again, but also post your code and say which part is not working as expected or giving errors. This here (stackoverflow.com/questions/12488605/…) is a nice simple example of providing some code, and then saying which part is not working, and asking one question about it. – dann.dev 16 hours ago

```
double averageNumber;
double sum;
sum = (number1 + number2 + number3);
averageNumber = (number1 + number2 + number3) /3; //Display results 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the three numbers is " + sum + "and the average of the numbers is " + averageNumber);
```

The last part of this code doesn't work. I expect the box to open and give me the sum and average. How do I find out what I am doing wrong? The first part works the box opens and you put in three numbers then I get nothing.

Comment: Have you debugged the application and made sure that the proposed code is executed?

Comment: Yeah, debugger would immensely help here to spot what does(n't) happen.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine. The problem is definitely not in the part you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

When I run

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    double number1 = 5, number2 = 6, number3 = 7;

    double averageNumber;
    double sum;
    sum = (number1 + number2 + number3);
    averageNumber = (number1 + number2 + number3) /3; //Display results
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the three numbers is " + sum + "and the average of the numbers is " + averageNumber);
}
```

it displays

[image: Displayed result]

If there is a problem it in not in the code you provided.

BTW: I would add a space after the `sum` ;)